# Filtering in frequency domain

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I'm trying to modify a transfer function in the frequency domain by filtering it with a Butterworth filter.
For example, let's say my transfer function is of the form :

```
myfunction[f_]:=HankelH1[1,f];
LogPlot[Abs[myfunction[f]], {f, 0, 10000}]
```

[image]

Then, I design a High[Pass Butterworth filter with cutoff frequency `fc=2000` :

```
filter = ButterworthFilterModel[{"HighPass", 3, 2 \[Pi]*2000}];
BodePlot[filter, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

[image]

filter is a `TransferFunctionModel` and `myfunction` is a function of frequency. Thus I don't really know how to multiply this two things in order to filter `myfunction` by `filter` in the frequency domain.

OutputResponse filters in time domain if I understood well, maybe I should define myfunction as a `TransferFunctionModel` ?

Comment: I think you can just use `filter[I f]` to get the filter value at frequency f

Comment: as simple as that.. I'm not use to the `TransferFunctionModel` objects. It can be evaluated as a function in fact. Thank you!